# SRSS - Double GROUPS from same SQL request in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm completly stuck as Im new to SSRS.

I have a set of data formed like this :

- A "Selection" of rights concerns several "Companies"
- A "Company" contains several "Conductors"
- A "Selection" is accessible by several "Accessors"

My SQL results look like this :

| SELECTION_NAME | COMPANY_NAME | CONDUCTORS_NAME | ACCESSORS_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SELECT_A | COMPANY_A | John | Maggie |
| SELECT_A | COMPANY_A | John | Lucy |
| SELECT_A | COMPANY_A | John | Veronica |
| SELECT_A | COMPANY_A | Bob | Maggie |
| SELECT_A | COMPANY_A | Bob | Lucy |
| SELECT_A | COMPANY_A | Bob | Veronica |
| SELECT_A | COMPANY_AA | Luke | Maggie |
| SELECT_A | COMPANY_AA | Luke | Lucy |
| SELECT_A | COMPANY_AA | Luke | Veronica |

as you can see, conductors are repeated as many time as there are accessors to the relative Selection.

I would like to have, in my SSRS report, a relatively same structure BUT I want that conductors, and associated accessors, listed each ONCE.
And, grouping by Selection > Company.

It could be something like this :

| SELECTION_NAME | COMPANY_NAME | CONDUCTORS_NAME | ACCESSORS_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SELECT_A | COMPANY_A |  |  |
|  |  | John | Maggie |
|  |  | Bob | Lucy |
|  |  |  | Veronica |
|  | COMPANY_AA |  |  |
|  |  | Luke | Maggie |
|  |  |  | Lucy |
|  |  |  | Veronica |

I tried to create 2 datasets and use LOOKUP but if it list conductors only once, at each line, I got the first accessor repeated, no more lines, no other accessors names..

How can I display `conductors` in 3rd column, regardless number of accessors, grouping by `SELECTION > Company` AND only `SELECTION accessors` in the 4th one regardless conductors and also grouping by `SELECTION > Company` (even if accessors will be repeated on each companies lines of the same Selection) ?

Is this possible with SSRS ?
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any ways to do it with only groups..

I created a **subreport** with accessors (linked to Selection > Company > Accessors).
I added it in a new column in the main report which only displays "Conductors" (Selection > Company > Conductors).

The only negative point is that it's really long charging report.. :/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do anything complicated.

Create a dataset that gives you the table you showed at the start of your question.

Then add a tablix (table) to your report.

There are several ways to create the design but if you start by dragging accessor onto the detail row. Now, under the main design windows you will see a section with Row Groups listed, you will only have one called "Detailed", now you can either drag the Conductor just above the detail row group, or you can right-click the detail row group and add a parent group and select Conductor. Repeat to add row groups for the other two columns.

The SSRS documentation explains this process in more detail

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15

He's quick GIF using your data to show you the basic steps. Notice that I drag the field names just above the existing row group name so that a blue line appears, then I release the mouse button.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I now have conductors once, but accessors are repeated at each conductors instead of once. My Arbo is (groups) : `Selection > Company > Conductors > Details (accessors)`